# How Do I Programmatically Change The SRC value of the images using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The images do not have unique `ids` nor do they have unique `classes`. How do I change the `src` value for each element from the array of images.

```
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img2.jpg" />
<img src="img3.jpg" />
<img src="img4.jpg" />
```

```js
var images = ['img11.jpg', 'img22.jpg','img33.jpg','img44.jpg'];
```

Comment: so select them by the tag and loop over them. `document.querySelectorAll().forEach()` is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is the index of the current iterated item.

Grab the image elements with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and then use `forEach` to iterate over them updating the `src` attribute of each image with the element at the appropriate index in the array.

```js
const arr = ['img11.jpg', 'img22.jpg','img33.jpg','img44.jpg'];

const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

images.forEach((image, index) => image.src = arr[index]);
```

```html
<img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img2.jpg" />
<img src="img3.jpg" />
<img src="img4.jpg" />
```